# Maintain size when re compressing stream to JPEG

Tags: ios, c#-4.0, xamarin, jpeg

I have a JPEG image of 5MB, I am converting it into stream and again recompressing it to JPEG to save at another location. What JPEG compression to apply (from 0.0 to 1.0) so that I can maintain size of the file?

Right now when I try to save the image without compressing I get a image file of 18 MB. And when I used

NSData data = objUIImage.AsJPEG(1.0f);

(logically, I have an image which is already JPEG compressed whose size is 5 MB, so without any compression I should get back a 5 MB image)

then I get an image of 19.5 MB :|

I am trying to do this in C# in a Xamarin.iOS application.

Thanks

Comment: An image in a `UIImage` is NOT in JPEG. It's stored in whatever format Apple feels is the best for displaying (it's in memory, not a file) (generally RGB data). You can't display a JPEG without first decompressing it - so `UIImage` decompresses the file while loading. If you want to save it back as a JPEG, you'll have to use whatever compression rate is best. If you really need to get the same size, you'll have to try different compressions until you find one that is close enough.

Comment: It might also be possible to simply the copy the original file or write the original stream out to a file (without using `UIImage` at all).